# Got "AttributeError: module 'faker.providers.en_US' has no attribute 'Provider'" Exception with python Faker module

Tags: python, python-3.x, faker

After install "**pip install Faker**", I did below:

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
```

Once I run above command, it's throw exception, Details as below:

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> fake = Faker()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Software\Python37\lib\site-packages\faker\factory.py", line 56, in create
    prov_cls, lang_found = cls._get_provider_class(prov_name, locale)
  File "E:\Software\Python37\lib\site-packages\faker\factory.py", line 67, in _get_provider_class
    provider_class = cls._find_provider_class(provider, locale)
  File "E:\Software\Python37\lib\site-packages\faker\factory.py", line 128, in _find_provider_class
    return provider_module.Provider
AttributeError: module 'faker.providers.en_US' has no attribute 'Provider'
>>>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of the library are you using?

Comment: Version: Faker==2.0.4